# AngularJS - jQuery returns collections of elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a chat directive that I've placed in 3 different places on my page. I'm doing this for responsive reasons showing the chat button in different places based on bootstrap's classes (visible-xs, hidden-xs, etc.) I've attached a click event in the directive to the chat button. The issue is that this is firing for each of the directive instances, and I would like it to only fire once. Below are some code snippets. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<div eb-chat 
     class="chatBtn hidden-xs hidden-sm">
  <img src="../common/images/chat.gif" alt="Live Chat">
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('ebChat', function () {
return {
    template: '',
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},
    link: function postLink(scope, element) {

        console.log('ran this many times');

        var chatClick = $(".chatBtn"),

        function openChatWindow() {
          console.log('open window');
        }

        chatClick.click(function () {
            openChatWindow();
        });

    }
};
});
```

Comment: You should use the element in link, not jquery.

Comment: `var chatClick = $(".chatBtn")` - returns **colection** of chats. If you want select one chat - you must change selector according to yours HTML document structure. Provide some more details will be helpful for investigating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you've muddled the element that is the focus in your directive. You'll want to refactor to NOT use JQuery as it isn't required in scenario as you can already bind to the element without having to leverage JQuery.

```
.directive('ebChat', function () {
return {
    template: '',
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {},
    link: function postLink(scope, element) {    
        function openChatWindow() {
          console.log('open window');
        }

        element.bind('click', function () {
            openChatWindow();
        });

    }
};
});
```

This will now only bind to your ebChat element that is specific to that element for this instance of the directive.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Needed to get this working asap!